# What is the divergence of a matrix valued function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

[According to Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Application_in_Cartesian_coordinates)

> The divergence of a continuously differentiable tensor field $\underline{\underline{\epsilon}}$ is:
>
> $$\overrightarrow{\operatorname{div}}\,(\mathbf{\underline{\underline{\epsilon}}}) = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \frac{\partial \epsilon_{xx}}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial \epsilon_{xy}}{\partial y} +\frac{\partial \epsilon_{xz}}{\partial z} \\
> \frac{\partial \epsilon_{yx}}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial \epsilon_{yy}}{\partial y} +\frac{\partial \epsilon_{yz}}{\partial z} \\
> \frac{\partial \epsilon_{zx}}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial \epsilon_{zy}}{\partial y} +\frac{\partial \epsilon_{zz}}{\partial z}
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

How do you get this formula from the definition of divergence? Either formally, or with some abuse of notation?

Comment: What is your definition of divergence?

Comment: Also you can work it out from the [definition of $\nabla$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del) notation.

Comment: I don't have a high enough reputation to comment, but note that the equation in the original post is not correct: $\epsilon_{ij}$ should be replaced with $\epsilon_{ji}$ in all of the term numerators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If S a matrix, with columns $S^{j}$, $j=1$, $n$ then $\mathrm{div}(S)_{j} = \mathrm{div}(S^{j})$.

Comment: +1. More generally, for any linear operator that acts on vectors, the natural extension to matrices is to apply the operator column-wise.

Comment: hmmm are you sure? I think this is not (always) right. consider a 3x2 matrix that depends on two variables.