# How to calculate the divergence of matrix?

Tags: matrices

The divergence of a vector field in Cartesian coordinate system (CCS) is defined as follows

$$ \mathrm{div}(\mathbf v) =  \nabla \cdot \mathbf v = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
v_3
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
v_3
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} &
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} &
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
v_3
\end{bmatrix} 
=\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x}+ 
\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial y}+
\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial z}
$$

where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product; it was changed to transposition with matrix multiplication. Now lets define some matrix

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} && a_{12} && a_{13} \\
a_{21} && a_{22} && a_{23} \\
a_{31} && a_{32} && a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How to calculate divergence of matrix in CCS and how looks its 'dot' product and 'matrix multiplication' form?

$$\mathrm{div}(A) = ?$$

Comment: as far I know, the divergence of matrix should give vector as a result

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78818/what-is-the-divergence-of-a-matrix-valued-function) might help

Comment: @mvpq thank for link, but someone told there in comments that forumla given in wiki is WRONG (idex-es are bad)

Comment: First calculate the gradient $\;g_{ij}=\partial_iv_j\;$ then calculate the divergence by contracting over the leading two indices, i.e. $\;\phi=\delta_{ij}g_{ij}=g_{ii}.\;$ This procedure can be extended to arbitrary tensors, just add more indices on the right, e.g. $$\eqalign{g_{ijklm}&=\partial_iv_{jklm}\\ \phi_{klm}&=\delta_{ij}g_{ijklm}=g_{iiklm}}$$

Comment: @greg in your approach (for 3x3 matrix) the div(A) will give scalar (if I read your formulas in good way) - but as far I know, the div(A) should give VECTOR as result

Comment: My approach yields a vector, just omit the $(l,m)$ indices everywhere. I'm using $\phi$ to represent the divergence, $g$ for the gradient, and $v$ to represent either $A$ or $v$.

Comment: @greg sorry, probably I read your formulas in wrong way - can I know what is $\phi$ (without indexes) and how it relate to div(A) ?

Comment: You use sloppy notation, then get confused. You take the divergence of a *vector field*, not of a vector. The partial derivatives of a constant vector field are all zero. You seem to be interested in "matrix fields". Just use the Frobenius inner product instead.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - yes of course, the `A` and `v` components are not constant - they are some functions dependent on x,y,z. But still there is a problem how to calclutate div(A). The Frobenius inner product gives SCALAR as result - but div(A) should give VECTOR as result

Comment: Then left-multiply by $\nabla$ or something. You need to define what the divergence of a "matrix field" is.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - no - I don't want to create new definition. As far as I know In math definition of general divergence (for arbitrary order tensors like matrix above) already  exists - but Im confused - people say that wiki definition has bugs with indexes.

Comment: Is Wikipedia the only place where such definitions are written? Have you tried Google Books?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this answer I use $x=x_1, y=x_2, z=x_3$ and [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). On wikipedia in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics)#Divergence_of_a_tensor_field) I found following information (in article they use S instead A) for CCS:

$$
\nabla\cdot A = \cfrac{\partial A_{ki}}{\partial x_k}~\mathbf{e}_i = A_{ki,k}~\mathbf{e}_i = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial a_{11}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial a_{21}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial a_{31}}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial a_{12}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial a_{22}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial a_{32}}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial a_{13}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial a_{23}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial a_{33}}{\partial z} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The result is contravariant (column) vector. But in [this article](http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/~pkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/Chapter_1_Vectors_Tensors/Vectors_Tensors_14_Tensor_Calculus.pdf) is mention that $\mathrm{div}(A) \neq \nabla\cdot A$ and

$$
\mathrm{div}(A) = \nabla\cdot A^T = \cfrac{\partial A_{ik}}{\partial x_k}~\mathbf{e}_i = A_{ik,k}~\mathbf{e}_i = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial a_{11}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial a_{12}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial a_{13}}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial a_{21}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial a_{22}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial a_{23}}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial a_{31}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial a_{32}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial a_{33}}{\partial z} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

When A is symetric: $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ then $\mathrm{div}(A) = \nabla\cdot A$

Wiki also mention that some authors use alternative definition: $\nabla\cdot A = \cfrac{\partial A_{ik}}{\partial x_k}~\mathbf{e}_i $ probably only for case when A is symmetric (for which that alternative definition is equal to original). However alternative definition is NOT compatible with general curvilinear definition which I found on wiki too:

$$
\nabla\cdot A
        = \left(\cfrac{\partial A_{ki}}{\partial x_k}- A_{li}~\Gamma_{kk}^l - A_{kl}~\Gamma_{ki}^l\right)~\mathbf{g}^i
$$

Comment: currently I don't know what is exact definition of: $\mathbf{g}^i$ - probably it will give something like $\mathbf{e}_i$ (?)